# JavaFX SubScene setFill

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I'm trying to set the background of a SubScene as an image, but when I do, this happens:

[image: Scene with a Box and Camera]

This is the code:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    Group model = new Group(new Box(200, 10, 10));
    Group course = new Group(model);
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    Pane pane1 = new Pane(course);
    SubScene subScene1 = new SubScene(pane1, 1000, 720);
    Group homeCameraXform = new Group();
    model.getChildren().add(homeCameraXform);
    homeCameraXform.getChildren().add(camera);
    subScene1.setCamera(camera);
    camera.setNearClip(.1);
    camera.setFarClip(10000);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-1000);
    Xform s = new Xform();
    s.getChildren().add(camera);
    subScene1.setOnMouseDragged(e -> s.rx.setAngle(s.rx.getAngle()+ 10));
    borderPane.setLeft(subScene1);
    subScene1.setFill(new ImagePattern(new Image("file.jpg")));
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1280,720, true);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

For a normal Scene with a depthBuffer, I just needed to do `scene.setFill(new ImagePattern(new Image("file")))`. When I try `setFill(Color.RED)` instead of `setFill(new ImagePattern(new Image("")))`, it works as expected. What else do I have to do to setFill with an ImagePattern?

Comment: Does this problem occur in the latest JavaFX (stable is 16, early access is 17)? Different operating systems? Different images? Are the other 3D shapes necessary to reproduce the problem? Narrow down the problem and if there is a definite issue consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: @Slaw No matter what kind of image I use (PNG, JPEG/JPG, BMP, or GIF), the box continues to be glitchy. I've even tried on Windows and Mac (I don't have access to a Linux operating system, but I assume that would be the same), and both systems have the issue of the one box getting redrawn constantly. I've also used JavaFX 16 and 17 on both systems, but the error still happens. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in JavaFX. I don't really have any ideas for a workaround. Does messing with the near/far clips of the camera change anything? In any case, I suggest creating a [mre] and [submitting a bug report](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) to see if they accept it.

Comment: Never had an issue with this. I can't run your code to test it. Did you submit a bug?

Comment: No, I'm still trying to see if there's anything else I can do. Could you post what code you wrote that didn't lead to the issue in my picture?

Answer (score 1):

**Using a skydome as 3d background**

This is a skydome :[image: skydome]

A 3d mesh usually made for realtime rendering. Its normal are pointing inside to see its texture from inside .

This is a single javafx app with two files you can test.
( you may notice that is the skydome is rotating not the camera . Camera motion is not implemented in this example)

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setTranslateY(-1.3);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-1.5);

        Shape3D cube = new Box(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
        cube.setTranslateY(-1.3);

        Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
        rotate.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3 * 10),
                        new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 360 * 10)));

        MeshView skyDome = getSkyDome();

        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        material.setDiffuseMap(new Image("/space.jpg"));
        skyDome.setMaterial(material);

        Group group3d = new Group(camera, skyDome, cube);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group3d, 640, 480, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        skyDome.getTransforms().setAll(rotate);

        timeline.play();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private MeshView getSkyDome() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("/skydome.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        return (MeshView) loader.getRoot();

    }

}
```

**skidome.fxml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <?import javafx.scene.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
    
    
        <MeshView id="default">
          
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>


    <MeshView id="default">
      <mesh>
        <TriangleMesh>
          <points>
            -0.094396, -2.432509, 0.474559, 0.094396, -2.432509, 0.474559, 0.0, -2.480165, 0.0, -0.342138, -1.753742, 1.720044, 0.342138, -1.753742, 1.720044, 0.268816, -2.062182, 1.35143, -0.268815, -2.062182, 1.351428, -0.402311, -1.377906, 2.022556, 0.402312, -1.377906, 2.022558, -0.447025, -0.949118, 2.247345, 0.447025, -0.949118, 2.247346, -0.474558, -0.483856, 2.385768, 0.474559, -0.483856, 2.385769, 0.268816, -2.432509, 0.402312, 0.185164, -2.291374, 0.930881, 0.527302, -2.291374, 0.789163, -0.185164, -2.291374, 0.930881, 0.789163, -2.291374, 0.527302, 0.402312, -2.432509, 0.268816, 0.765523, -2.062182, 1.145687, 0.974327, -1.753742, 1.458183, 1.145687, -1.377906, 1.714641, 1.273019, -0.949118, 1.905208, 1.35143, -0.483856, 2.022558, 0.483856, 0.0, 2.432509, 1.377906, 0.0, 2.062182, 0.474559, -2.432509, 0.094396, 0.402312, -2.432509, -0.268816, 0.268816, -2.432509, -0.402312, 1.145687, -2.062182, 0.765523, 1.458183, -1.753742, 0.974327, 1.714641, -1.377906, 1.145687, 1.905207, -0.949118, 1.273019, 2.022558, -0.483856, 1.35143, 2.062182, 0.0, 1.377905, 1.35143, -2.062182, 0.268816, 0.930881, -2.291374, 0.185164, 1.720044, -1.753742, 0.342138, 2.022557, -1.377906, 0.402312, 2.247345, -0.949118, 0.447025, 2.385769, -0.483856, 0.474559, 2.432509, 0.0, 0.483856, 0.789163, -2.291374, -0.527302, 0.527302, -2.291374, -0.789163, 1.35143, -2.062182, -0.268816, 0.930881, -2.291374, -0.185164, 1.720044, -1.753742, -0.342138, 2.022557, -1.377906, -0.402312, 2.247345, -0.949118, -0.447025, 2.385769, -0.483856, -0.474559, 2.432509, 0.0, -0.483856, 0.474559, -2.432509, -0.094396, 1.458183, -1.753742, -0.974326, 1.145687, -2.062182, -0.765523, 1.714641, -1.377906, -1.145687, 1.905207, -0.949118, -1.273019, 2.022557, -0.483856, -1.35143, 2.062181, 0.0, -1.377906, -0.483855, 0.0, 2.432507, 0.974326, -1.753742, -1.458183, 0.765523, -2.062182, -1.145687, 1.145686, -1.377906, -1.714641, 1.273019, -0.949118, -1.905207, 1.351429, -0.483856, -2.022557, 1.377905, 0.0, -2.062181, 0.185164, -2.291374, -0.930881, 0.094396, -2.432509, -0.474559, 0.402311, -1.377906, -2.022557, 0.342138, -1.753742, -1.720044, 0.447025, -0.949118, -2.247345, 0.474559, -0.483856, -2.385769, 0.483855, 0.0, -2.432508, -0.185164, -2.291374, -0.930881, -0.094396, -2.432509, -0.474559, 0.268816, -2.062182, -1.351429, -0.447025, -0.949118, -2.247345, -0.402312, -1.377906, -2.022557, -0.474559, -0.483856, -2.385769, -0.483857, 0.0, -2.432508, -0.527302, -2.291374, -0.789163, -0.268816, -2.432509, -0.402311, -0.268816, -2.062182, -1.351429, -0.342138, -1.753742, -1.720044, -1.273019, -0.949118, -1.905207, -1.145687, -1.377906, -1.714641, -1.35143, -0.483856, -2.022557, -1.377906, 0.0, -2.06218, -0.789163, -2.291374, -0.527301, -0.402311, -2.432509, -0.268816, -0.765523, -2.062182, -1.145686, -0.974326, -1.753742, -1.458183, -2.022557, -0.483856, -1.351429, -1.905207, -0.949118, -1.273019, -2.062181, 0.0, -1.377904, -0.930881, -2.291374, -0.185164, -0.474559, -2.432509, -0.094396, -1.145686, -2.062182, -0.765523, -1.458183, -1.753742, -0.974326, -1.714641, -1.377906, -1.145686, -2.385769, -0.483856, -0.474558, -2.247345, -0.949118, -0.447025, -2.432508, 0.0, -0.483855, -0.930881, -2.291374, 0.185164, -0.474559, -2.432509, 0.094396, -1.351429, -2.062182, -0.268816, -1.720044, -1.753742, -0.342138, -2.022557, -1.377906, -0.402311, -2.432507, 0.0, 0.483857, -2.385768, -0.483856, 0.47456, -0.789162, -2.291374, 0.527302, -0.402311, -2.432509, 0.268816, -1.351429, -2.062182, 0.268816, -1.720044, -1.753742, 0.342138, -2.022557, -1.377906, 0.402312, -2.247345, -0.949118, 0.447025, -0.527301, -2.291374, 0.789163, -0.268816, -2.432509, 0.402311, -1.145686, -2.062182, 0.765523, -1.458182, -1.753742, 0.974326, -1.71464, -1.377906, 1.145687, -1.905207, -0.949118, 1.273019, -2.022556, -0.483856, 1.35143, -2.062179, 0.0, 1.377906, -0.765522, -2.062182, 1.145686, -0.974326, -1.753742, 1.458183, -1.145686, -1.377906, 1.714641, -1.273018, -0.949118, 1.905207, -1.351429, -0.483856, 2.022557, -1.377903, 0.0, 2.06218
          </points>
          <texCoords>
            0.474147, 0.554411, 0.459173, 0.542211, 0.497469, 0.510688, 0.401617, 0.69249904, 0.339297, 0.642836, 0.381025, 0.607478, 0.426818, 0.644186, 0.374268, 0.745052, 0.294258, 0.681365, 0.344075, 0.803576, 0.244831, 0.72359, 0.310262, 0.86816204, 0.188605, 0.77230597, 0.450007, 0.52519, 0.420663, 0.57419896, 0.402144, 0.54010296, 0.450793, 0.598541, 0.398004, 0.501432, 0.448031, 0.505932, 0.352741, 0.55584896, 0.300594, 0.57283497, 0.244277, 0.59156096, 0.182, 0.612661, 0.111153, 0.637178, 0.123258, 0.82906103, 0.027992, 0.666368, 0.453578, 0.48735303, 0.482963, 0.463072, 0.502329, 0.46113402, 0.346159, 0.49715102, 0.291204, 0.49302697, 0.231585, 0.488998, 0.165286, 0.484999, 0.089498, 0.480954, 1.0E-4, 0.47660702, 0.362536, 0.440125, 0.408982, 0.464001, 0.313039, 0.415165, 0.259036, 0.38845903, 0.198627, 0.359159, 0.129173, 0.32611, 0.046856, 0.28750902, 0.468006, 0.41481602, 0.507085, 0.41079903, 0.399699, 0.393515, 0.43354, 0.43354303, 0.363408, 0.351206, 0.323555, 0.30540198, 0.278658, 0.25451702, 0.226602, 0.196352, 0.164136, 0.127671, 0.465839, 0.47228998, 0.434986, 0.311454, 0.452158, 0.364707, 0.415973, 0.253478, 0.394455, 0.188712, 0.369528, 0.11443597, 0.339115, 0.022300005, 0.268737, 0.947176, 0.51661, 0.30255198, 0.511808, 0.35838902, 0.521646, 0.24165797, 0.527191, 0.17353898, 0.533629, 0.09482598, 0.542525, 0.0026819706, 0.544709, 0.422158, 0.520958, 0.466788, 0.623624, 0.271716, 0.595337, 0.32599097, 0.655278, 0.21057498, 0.691454, 0.14150602, 0.733968, 0.058188975, 0.57503, 0.44712198, 0.535978, 0.47915798, 0.569293, 0.375632, 0.758412, 0.295969, 0.705741, 0.33930302, 0.819598, 0.24593401, 0.893654, 0.18697703, 0.593374, 0.481776, 0.545089, 0.49633002, 0.615601, 0.41373003, 0.658739, 0.378128, 0.819903, 0.41351098, 0.754973, 0.432998, 0.895401, 0.392321, 0.984045, 0.368082, 0.596988, 0.52072, 0.546915, 0.51565504, 0.643545, 0.46662802, 0.696888, 0.45051098, 0.90723, 0.554314, 0.831046, 0.544786, 0.9999, 0.565755, 0.585435, 0.557967, 0.541211, 0.534176, 0.648957, 0.525985, 0.704147, 0.531596, 0.764159, 0.537763, 0.85742, 0.706935, 0.791173, 0.669206, 0.934559, 0.751607, 0.560597, 0.58788097, 0.52888, 0.549083, 0.631263, 0.582636, 0.679851, 0.608819, 0.732569, 0.637317, 0.810515, 0.896712, 0.75453, 0.82741296, 0.526317, 0.606017, 0.511816, 0.55813897, 0.59343, 0.628034, 0.628208, 0.670555, 0.665895, 0.716673, 0.707717, 0.76798403, 0.487793, 0.609733, 0.492608, 0.56000197, 0.541351, 0.655504, 0.557295, 0.707849, 0.574561, 0.76454103, 0.593638, 0.827516, 0.614138, 0.899719, 0.637505, 0.984956, 0.482914, 0.66112, 0.47785, 0.715472, 0.47246, 0.774325, 0.466571, 0.839563, 0.45879, 0.913558, 0.450524, 0.9999
          </texCoords>
          <faces>
            0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 4, 4, 7, 7, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 9, 10, 10, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 11, 11, 12, 12, 10, 10, 11, 11, 10, 10, 9, 9, 1, 1, 13, 13, 2, 2, 14, 14, 15, 15, 13, 13, 14, 14, 13, 13, 1, 1, 6, 6, 5, 5, 14, 14, 6, 6, 14, 14, 16, 16, 15, 15, 17, 17, 18, 18, 15, 15, 18, 18, 13, 13, 13, 13, 18, 18, 2, 2, 5, 5, 19, 19, 15, 15, 5, 5, 15, 15, 14, 14, 4, 4, 20, 20, 19, 19, 4, 4, 19, 19, 5, 5, 8, 8, 21, 21, 20, 20, 8, 8, 20, 20, 4, 4, 10, 10, 22, 22, 21, 21, 10, 10, 21, 21, 8, 8, 12, 12, 23, 23, 22, 22, 12, 12, 22, 22, 10, 10, 24, 24, 25, 25, 23, 23, 24, 24, 23, 23, 12, 12, 18, 18, 26, 26, 2, 2, 27, 27, 28, 28, 2, 2, 19, 19, 29, 29, 17, 17, 19, 19, 17, 17, 15, 15, 20, 20, 30, 30, 29, 29, 20, 20, 29, 29, 19, 19, 21, 21, 31, 31, 30, 30, 21, 21, 30, 30, 20, 20, 22, 22, 32, 32, 31, 31, 22, 22, 31, 31, 21, 21, 23, 23, 33, 33, 32, 32, 23, 23, 32, 32, 22, 22, 25, 25, 34, 34, 33, 33, 25, 25, 33, 33, 23, 23, 29, 29, 35, 35, 36, 36, 29, 29, 36, 36, 17, 17, 30, 30, 37, 37, 35, 35, 30, 30, 35, 35, 29, 29, 31, 31, 38, 38, 37, 37, 31, 31, 37, 37, 30, 30, 32, 32, 39, 39, 38, 38, 32, 32, 38, 38, 31, 31, 33, 33, 40, 40, 39, 39, 33, 33, 39, 39, 32, 32, 34, 34, 41, 41, 40, 40, 34, 34, 40, 40, 33, 33, 42, 42, 43, 43, 28, 28, 42, 42, 28, 28, 27, 27, 17, 17, 36, 36, 26, 26, 17, 17, 26, 26, 18, 18, 35, 35, 44, 44, 45, 45, 35, 35, 45, 45, 36, 36, 37, 37, 46, 46, 44, 44, 37, 37, 44, 44, 35, 35, 38, 38, 47, 47, 46, 46, 38, 38, 46, 46, 37, 37, 39, 39, 48, 48, 47, 47, 39, 39, 47, 47, 38, 38, 40, 40, 49, 49, 48, 48, 40, 40, 48, 48, 39, 39, 41, 41, 50, 50, 49, 49, 41, 41, 49, 49, 40, 40, 26, 26, 51, 51, 2, 2, 45, 45, 42, 42, 27, 27, 45, 45, 27, 27, 51, 51, 46, 46, 52, 52, 53, 53, 46, 46, 53, 53, 44, 44, 47, 47, 54, 54, 52, 52, 47, 47, 52, 52, 46, 46, 48, 48, 55, 55, 54, 54, 48, 48, 54, 54, 47, 47, 49, 49, 56, 56, 55, 55, 49, 49, 55, 55, 48, 48, 50, 50, 57, 57, 56, 56, 50, 50, 56, 56, 49, 49, 51, 51, 27, 27, 2, 2, 58, 58, 24, 24, 12, 12, 58, 58, 12, 12, 11, 11, 44, 44, 53, 53, 42, 42, 44, 44, 42, 42, 45, 45, 52, 52, 59, 59, 60, 60, 52, 52, 60, 60, 53, 53, 54, 54, 61, 61, 59, 59, 54, 54, 59, 59, 52, 52, 55, 55, 62, 62, 61, 61, 55, 55, 61, 61, 54, 54, 56, 56, 63, 63, 62, 62, 56, 56, 62, 62, 55, 55, 57, 57, 64, 64, 63, 63, 57, 57, 63, 63, 56, 56, 43, 43, 65, 65, 66, 66, 43, 43, 66, 66, 28, 28, 28, 28, 66, 66, 2, 2, 53, 53, 60, 60, 43, 43, 53, 53, 43, 43, 42, 42, 61, 61, 67, 67, 68, 68, 61, 61, 68, 68, 59, 59, 62, 62, 69, 69, 67, 67, 62, 62, 67, 67, 61, 61, 63, 63, 70, 70, 69, 69, 63, 63, 69, 69, 62, 62, 64, 64, 71, 71, 70, 70, 64, 64, 70, 70, 63, 63, 65, 65, 72, 72, 73, 73, 65, 65, 73, 73, 66, 66, 66, 66, 73, 73, 2, 2, 60, 60, 74, 74, 65, 65, 60, 60, 65, 65, 43, 43, 59, 59, 68, 68, 74, 74, 59, 59, 74, 74, 60, 60, 69, 69, 75, 75, 76, 76, 69, 69, 76, 76, 67, 67, 70, 70, 77, 77, 75, 75, 70, 70, 75, 75, 69, 69, 71, 71, 78, 78, 77, 77, 71, 71, 77, 77, 70, 70, 72, 72, 79, 79, 80, 80, 72, 72, 80, 80, 73, 73, 73, 73, 80, 80, 2, 2, 74, 74, 81, 81, 72, 72, 74, 74, 72, 72, 65, 65, 68, 68, 82, 82, 81, 81, 68, 68, 81, 81, 74, 74, 67, 67, 76, 76, 82, 82, 67, 67, 82, 82, 68, 68, 75, 75, 83, 83, 84, 84, 75, 75, 84, 84, 76, 76, 77, 77, 85, 85, 83, 83, 77, 77, 83, 83, 75, 75, 78, 78, 86, 86, 85, 85, 78, 78, 85, 85, 77, 77, 79, 79, 87, 87, 88, 88, 79, 79, 88, 88, 80, 80, 80, 80, 88, 88, 2, 2, 81, 81, 89, 89, 79, 79, 81, 81, 79, 79, 72, 72, 82, 82, 90, 90, 89, 89, 82, 82, 89, 89, 81, 81, 76, 76, 84, 84, 90, 90, 76, 76, 90, 90, 82, 82, 85, 85, 91, 91, 92, 92, 85, 85, 92, 92, 83, 83, 86, 86, 93, 93, 91, 91, 86, 86, 91, 91, 85, 85, 87, 87, 94, 94, 95, 95, 87, 87, 95, 95, 88, 88, 88, 88, 95, 95, 2, 2, 89, 89, 96, 96, 87, 87, 89, 89, 87, 87, 79, 79, 90, 90, 97, 97, 96, 96, 90, 90, 96, 96, 89, 89, 84, 84, 98, 98, 97, 97, 84, 84, 97, 97, 90, 90, 83, 83, 92, 92, 98, 98, 83, 83, 98, 98, 84, 84, 91, 91, 99, 99, 100, 100, 91, 91, 100, 100, 92, 92, 93, 93, 101, 101, 99, 99, 93, 93, 99, 99, 91, 91, 94, 94, 102, 102, 103, 103, 94, 94, 103, 103, 95, 95, 95, 95, 103, 103, 2, 2, 96, 96, 104, 104, 94, 94, 96, 96, 94, 94, 87, 87, 97, 97, 105, 105, 104, 104, 97, 97, 104, 104, 96, 96, 98, 98, 106, 106, 105, 105, 98, 98, 105, 105, 97, 97, 92, 92, 100, 100, 106, 106, 92, 92, 106, 106, 98, 98, 101, 101, 107, 107, 108, 108, 101, 101, 108, 108, 99, 99, 102, 102, 109, 109, 110, 110, 102, 102, 110, 110, 103, 103, 103, 103, 110, 110, 2, 2, 104, 104, 111, 111, 102, 102, 104, 104, 102, 102, 94, 94, 105, 105, 112, 112, 111, 111, 105, 105, 111, 111, 104, 104, 106, 106, 113, 113, 112, 112, 106, 106, 112, 112, 105, 105, 100, 100, 114, 114, 113, 113, 100, 100, 113, 113, 106, 106, 99, 99, 108, 108, 114, 114, 99, 99, 114, 114, 100, 100, 109, 109, 115, 115, 116, 116, 109, 109, 116, 116, 110, 110, 110, 110, 116, 116, 2, 2, 111, 111, 117, 117, 109, 109, 111, 111, 109, 109, 102, 102, 112, 112, 118, 118, 117, 117, 112, 112, 117, 117, 111, 111, 113, 113, 119, 119, 118, 118, 113, 113, 118, 118, 112, 112, 114, 114, 120, 120, 119, 119, 114, 114, 119, 119, 113, 113, 108, 108, 121, 121, 120, 120, 108, 108, 120, 120, 114, 114, 107, 107, 122, 122, 121, 121, 107, 107, 121, 121, 108, 108, 115, 115, 16, 16, 0, 0, 115, 115, 0, 0, 116, 116, 116, 116, 0, 0, 2, 2, 117, 117, 123, 123, 115, 115, 117, 117, 115, 115, 109, 109, 118, 118, 124, 124, 123, 123, 118, 118, 123, 123, 117, 117, 119, 119, 125, 125, 124, 124, 119, 119, 124, 124, 118, 118, 120, 120, 126, 126, 125, 125, 120, 120, 125, 125, 119, 119, 121, 121, 127, 127, 126, 126, 121, 121, 126, 126, 120, 120, 122, 122, 128, 128, 127, 127, 122, 122, 127, 127, 121, 121, 123, 123, 6, 6, 16, 16, 123, 123, 16, 16, 115, 115, 124, 124, 3, 3, 6, 6, 124, 124, 6, 6, 123, 123, 125, 125, 7, 7, 3, 3, 125, 125, 3, 3, 124, 124, 126, 126, 9, 9, 7, 7, 126, 126, 7, 7, 125, 125, 127, 127, 11, 11, 9, 9, 127, 127, 9, 9, 126, 126, 128, 128, 58, 58, 11, 11, 128, 128, 11, 11, 127, 127, 16, 16, 14, 14, 1, 1, 16, 16, 1, 1, 0, 0, 36, 36, 45, 45, 51, 51, 36, 36, 51, 51, 26, 26
          </faces>
          <faceSmoothingGroups>
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
          </faceSmoothingGroups>
        </TriangleMesh>
      </mesh>
    </MeshView>
```

**space.jpg**

[image: polar coordinate texture]

**Result**

[image]